# Tab-completion of shell patterns

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion, readline

On my Debian servers I'm used to hitting Tab to "preview" the expansion of shell patterns:

```
$ cp *some*<Tab>
something  somewhat  have-some-cake
$ cp *some*_
```

When the pattern expands to one entry, Tab replaces the pattern with the actual entry; otherwise it shows a list of matching entries. This is intuitive and useful because it's consistent with the regular "prefix" Tab completion.

But my Ubuntu servers and desktops behave differently: even when it would expand to more than one entry, **Tab replaces the pattern with the first entry.**

I have checked the usual suspects (/etc/bash.bashrc, /etc/inputrc, and the local versions) and I couldn't find any difference.

Does anybody know which setting controls this behaviour?

Comment: Not true for me on Lubuntu 16.04.3, <Tab> shows the list of matching entries as expected. I use Ubuntu since 12.04 and never experienced a different behaviour – which flavour(s), version(s) and shell(s) do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary [the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/978876/760903), *this* particular problem is probably a direct result of using bash-completion. The bash-completion package has several bugs (as noted in [this U&L answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278449/260978) about a similar problem, for instance).

If I comment out this section in my `.bashrc`:

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

and start a new instance of bash, then I get:

```
$ echo *o*<tab><tab>
foo     food    foo.sh  
$ echo *o*
```

And then if I source the `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` script like it was in the `.bashrc`:

```
$ . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
$ echo foo
```

The `*o*` was immediately autocompleted to `foo` without showing the other matches.

I'm using 16.04, by the way. I don't know if this has been fixed in newer releases.

```
$ dpkg-query --show --showformat='${Package} ${version}\n' bash bash-completion
bash 4.3-14ubuntu1.2
bash-completion 1:2.1-4.2ubuntu1.1
```

Comment: Awesome, you found the culprit! Now I know where to start debugging

Answer (score 0):

Smarter tab completion in Bash requires the `bash-completion` package.

```
sudo apt install bash-completion
```

[Bash Completion](https://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) is actually written and maintained by Debian directly.
(See also its [Debian package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/bash-completion) and [Ubuntu package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion) pages.)

Once it is installed, it either loads automatically (e.g. via `/etc/bash.bashrc`) or else you'll need to instruct Bash to load it in your `~/.bashrc` with a stanza like this:

```
if [[ -z "$BASH_COMPLETION" ]] && [[ -r /etc/bash_completion ]]; then
  . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Before Red Hat and others included this package, I used to manually copy `/etc/bash_completion*` between systems.  This will work quite well, but I do not suggest it; it also cuts off the opportunity for your package manager to update existing completions and install new ones (which now go in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/` though they originally lived with your custom completions in `/etc/bash_completion.d/`).